# Multi monitor frustration

Tags: graphics-cards, memory, multiple-monitors

what is the best GPU/Card to use for my work-only rig. I do mainly dev work, Webdesign, massive multitasking with sometimes over 50 browser tabs open on each monitor. I don't game on this PC at all.

My current Hardware:

- CPU: i5 4690 @ 3.50GHz
- Geforce GTX 750Ti
- 32 GB RAM
- Total of 3 Screens: 2 WQHD screens with a res of 2560 x 1440
- 1 FHD Screen

Screens are connected with HDMI and 2 with DVI since the Card does not have DP.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the various extra questions you asked, because they weren't on-topic for this site. The question of which GPU is your best bet for your use is on topic, so that's what I've narrowed it down to.

Comment: Asking what is the best for a situation can bring in a lot of opinion-based answers, as everyone has their own definition for what is best.

Comment: Your existing card should be able to handle 3 monitors @1440p with ease: http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications. It is not clear what you are missing/struggling with.